# How can I post this data using C# to webservice (JSON data)

Tags: c#, json

Here is the python code: (I need to get it working in C#).

```
import requests #requires "requests" package
import json
response = requests.post('https://scm.commerceinterface.com/api/v2/mark_exported', 
                       data={'supplier_id':'1', 'token':'xYRPKcoakMoiRzWgKLV5TqPSdNAaZQT', 
                             'ci_lineitem_ids':json.dumps([54553919, 54553920])}).json()
if response['success'] == True:
   #Successfully marked as exported (only items which are not already marked exported)
   pass
else:
   pass
```

How can I format the string as necessary, and am I missing any necessary code? I currently have no way of testing the code with actual data.

Here is the C# code thus far:

```
public void postResponse(string supplierid, string token, string geturl, string lineid)
{

    try
    {
        lineid = lineid.Trim();
         string postdata = ("{'supplier_id':'"+supplierid+"','token':'"+token+"','ci_lineitem_ids':["+lineid+"]}");
        WebClient postWithParamsClient = new WebClient();
        postWithParamsClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postWithParamsClient.Headers["Content-Length"] = postdata.Length.ToString();
        postWithParamsClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(geturl),
                                                   "POST",
                                                   postdata);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to figure out what the call `json.dumps([54553919, 54553920])` produces in python, i.e. what string is output from that.  In C# `json.dumps()` is not a method, and you need to start with what string does it produce in python in order to reverse engineer in C#.  It's probably just a json array.

Comment: do you have any problems with C# code? what exactly does not work?

Comment: Are you asking how to serialize/deserialize the JSON data? .NET has the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this situation.

Comment: why not use a real webservice client?

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik - Define "real webservice client".

Comment: using System.Web.Services;

Comment: in your visual studio add server reference to the endpoint of the url your are supposed to https://scm.commerceinterface.com/api/v2/mark_exported

if its a web services like they say they do, magic will happen after you hit connect